# Raspberry Pi updated and now Mount Error

Tags: hard-drive

My Raspberry Pi updated and am now getting this error when running the sudo mount -a command.

mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported

Comment: Could you share the exact entry, please? I assume this is a line in your /etc/fstab file??

Comment: No this is the message I get when I run the sudo mount -a command.... It was working fine till yesterday....
Am a linux novice btw.

Comment: Please let me be clear: Are you saying that your `etc/fstab` entry is: `mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported` ?   Surely not... Can you show us the `etc/fstab` entry (a line in that file) that you use to mount the NFS drive?

Comment: `My Raspberry Pi updated` .... what does this mean?  .....updated software or replaced RPI?

Comment: 192.168.1.104:/Public   /home/pi/MyNAS  nfs   rw  0  0
That is the efc/stab entry...
The message is received when I noticed the drive was not mounted and I ran the "sudo mount - a" command. 
Updated Software - the "sudo apt-get update" command was run and when the device was rebooted, there was a message that the Debian system had been updated as well...

Comment: Can you try "apt-get install nfs-common" ?

Comment: Had to try that as root - says the most uptodate version is installed

Comment: Can you show us the export on the server?

Comment: 192.168.1.104:/Public/Movies   /home/pi/Movies  nfs   rw  0  0
192.168.1.104:/Public   /home/pi/MyNAS  nfs   rw  0  0
192.168.1.104:/Public/tv  /home/pi/TVShows  nfs  rw 0  0
192.168.1.104:/Public/drone /home/pi/Downloads nfs rw 0 0

Comment: The above was working fine till about 3 days ago.... Don't know what setting has changed.